# Separar con guiones los dígitos impares de un número

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmos

Estoy intentando hacer una función en **javascript** que dado un numero **n** separe sus dígitos impares de los pares con el caracter `'-'`.. si son 2 pares consecutivos no se separan, impares consecutivos se separan..

> *Ej1:* `function separarImpares(24589)` -> `(24-5-8-9)`
>
> *Ej2:* `function separarImpares(132479)` -> `(1-3-24-7-9)`

Pongo un ejemplo de código de lo que he probado. Gracias.

```js
function separarImpares(num) {
    let str="";
    num = `${num}`.split('');    
    for(var i=0; i<num.length; i++){
        switch (num[i]) {
            case (num[i]%2==0 & num[i+1]%2!=0 ):
                str+=`${num[i]}-`;
                console.log(num[i]);  
                break;
            case (num[i]%2!=0 & num[i+1]%2!=0):
                str+=`${num[i]}-`;
                break;
            case (num[i]%2!=0 & num[i+1]%2==0):
                str+=`${num[i]}-`;
                break;
            default:
                str+=`${num[i]}`
                break;
      }
    }
    return str
}

console.log(separarImpares(6815))
```

Comment: No es mucho pero mucho mas simple, recorrer el numero digito a digito, y si es par pasarlo al nuevo array como esta, y si es impar pasar -numero- al nuevo array? eso solo transforma tu funcion en un if sin importar que viene despues.. Salvo que no es lo que quieras, y entonces no se entiende que queres...

Comment: disculpa, ¿y que debería pasar si 2 números impares van juntos?

Comment: se separan @the-breaker a la vez que aparece un impar se pone el guion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedo proponer 2 enfoques de como resolverlo de forma muy simplificada:

**1.** Puedes recorrer el numero y preguntar dígito por dígito si es impar o no, luego ir acumulando el resultado en una cadena:

```js
function separarImpares (num, nsi=''){
  num = num.toString().split('').map(i => i%2 ? nsi+=`-${i}-` : nsi+=i);
  return nsi.split('-').filter(String).join('-')
}
console.log(separarImpares(24598513067));
```

Se emplea `toString()` para pasar el número a cadena, luego `split('')` para dividir el numero y `map()` para recorrer el array y acumular los dígitos en una cadena (`nsi`) que luego será retornada como resultado.

Para eliminar el exceso de guiones y los del principio y el final del resultado se puede usar:

```
split('-').filter(String).join('-')
```

**2.** Puedes recorren un array con los números impares reemplazando cada dígito impar de la cadena por el mismo con guiones usando `split()` y `join()`:

```js
function separarImpares (num, n=[1,3,5,7,9]){
  n.map(i => num = num.toString().split(i).join(`-${i}-`));
  return num.split('-').filter(String).join('-');
}
console.log(separarImpares(24598513067));
```

Se emplea la misma función para eliminar el exceso de guiones. Aunque este método podría ser menos optimo es otra forma de resolverlo. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias  se entiende muy bien se aprenden muchas cosas aca viendo este tipo de respuestas @the-breaker...  PD: no se pq a veces no me deja mencionar a las personas con el @, el otro dia me lo dijistes y arriba me dejo, pero ya ahora no puedo mencionarte gracias crack

Comment: de nada @IsraelGonzález, no tenia pensado responder, es importante que establezcas bien el problema desde el principio. Luego sobre el @ solo funciona si el usuario ya ha dejado un comentario.

Answer (score 4):

Usando una expresión regular en `split()` sería un enfoque totalmente distinto y reduce un poco el código:

```js
const num = 2458936;

const res = `${num}`.split(/([13579])/g).slice(0,-1).join("-").replace(/--/g, '-');

console.log(res);
```

Iterando, yo usaría `[...'${num}']` para pasar de numero a array y luego `%2` para cada número:

```js
const num = 2458936;

const res = [...`${num}`].map((e,i,a)=>(e%2)?(i<a.length -1)?`-${e}-`:`-${e}`:e).join("").replace(/--/g, '-');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: falta un guión entre el 5 y el 8

Comment: @PabloLozano corregido, había interpretado que era un guion a la izquierda, gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias! @Emeeus :)

Comment: @Emeeus en la segunda funcion cuando se introducen dos numeros impares consecutivos no penultimo numero se repite el guion... probe con `num=2458936` y me regresa por consola `24-5-8-9--3-6` como se puede arreglar??

Comment: y lo mismo pasa con la expresion regular

Answer (score 1):

Tomando de las 2 respuestas hice tambien esta funcion y la comparto... gracias a @Emeeus y @the-breaker..

```js
function separarImpares(num) {
    return `${num}`.split(/([13579])/g).filter(String).join('-')
}

console.log(separarImpares(6815297))
```

Otra cosa... si el numero es negativo impar entonces quedaria un `'--'` al principio del numero y si es negativo par quedaria negativo (un `'-'`) algo q tal vez no te interese si estas tratando el numero como una cadena a separar, esto seria mas sencillo depende de lo que quieras hacer (dejarlo negativo sin el doble -- o el primer numero par negativo cosa que puedes hacer con un `replace('--', '-)`))

**Mostrar como una cadena**

```js
function separarImpares(num) {
    (num<0) ? num=num*-1 :null
      return `${num}`.split(/([13579])/g).filter(String).join('-');
    };

console.log(separarImpares(-18185))
```